# Hadoop streaming job create huge temp files

Tags: hadoop, mapper

I was trying to run hadoop job to do the word shingling, and all my nodes soon get unhealthy state since the storage is used up.

Here is my mapper part:

```
shingle = 5

for line in sys.stdin:
# remove leading and trailing whitespace
line = line.strip()

for i in range(0, len(line)-shingle+1):
    print ('%s\t%s' % (line[i:i+shingle], 1))
```

For my understanding that 'print' will generate temp file on each node which occupy stroage space. If I took a txt file as an example:

```
cat README.txt |./shingle_mapper.py >> temp.txt
```

I can see the size of the original and temp file:

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1366 Nov 13 02:46 README.txt

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9744 Nov 14 01:43 temp.txt

The temp file size is over 7 times of the input file, so I guess this is the reason that each of my node is used up all storage.

My question is do I understand the temp file correctly? If so, is there any better way to reduce the size of temp files (adding additional storage is not an option for me)?

Comment: Try using combiner.

Comment: I tried combiner but got the same result. I think the temp files created by mapper job are still in huge size, my understanding is that the combiner can only reduce network traffic when sending data to reducers.